# Lexicographically Sort

Tags: java, sorting

I am using linkedlists to add() elements, I was wondering how I can lexicographically sort them so I can output them. Or would I have to create my own function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your elements implement `Comparable`, you can do this:

```
Collections.sort(mylist);
```

Many java standard classes such as String, Integer, etc, already implement Comparable - if your lists hold these types, there's nothing special you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

See [Collections.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).